# Typescript Object.keys() always returns an empty array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

First of all, I would like to mention that although this question has been asked several times before, none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Basically, I am using Ionic React, and at one point in my code, I have an Object which I declare as:

```
const [allArrays, setAllArrays] = useState<AllArraysObject>({});
```

`AllArraysObject` is a custom type which is declared in another file as:

```
export interface myType{
  a: number,
  b: string,
  ...
}

export type AllArraysObject= {
  [key: string]: myType[]
}
```

What I actually expect to create is an object which looks like this:

```
{
    "1": [
        {a: 10, b: "Hello", ...},
        {a: 11, b: "Hi", ...},
        ...
    ],
    ...
}
```

which is essentially an *Object of Arrays of Objects*. The Issue is that I cannot use `Object.keys(AllArrays)` to get an array of all the keys of the object (like `["1", "2", ...]`). I have used the same method previously in the application when it worked perfectly fine (at that point, I had an Object of *objects*).

I have tried the following:

```
Object.keys(allArrays)
Object.keys(allArrays as Object)
Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(allArrays)))
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(allArrays)
```

each of which returns me an empty `Array(0)`. As expected, if I `console.log(allArrays)`, I can see all the properties of the object, and on running the above-mentioned functions in the console, I do get the desired output.

---

I wish to know what mistake I am committing here (which could possibly be because of a gap in my understanding of how Objects work) and I also seek an explanation of the above behavior. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: it is `allArrays` and `allQueues` a typo and you are actually doing `Object.keys(allArrays)`?

Comment: Can you post how are you filling the state. If you console log the `allArrays` object, it shows something?

Comment: @ludwiguer Thank you for pointing it out. It was a typo and I have edited the question

Comment: @ludwiguer Yes,  if I console log `allArrays`, I get the the correct output. For filling the state, I am putting in one array at a time.

Comment: Working for me :/

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=29#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EG8BQFUQEQEZ0C4IG0U00Fo9MAGAGggCM90AJEYYAe3QgF8qjjUEUcphr0MjAJboefCAF0kXJMoDGbAHYBnNqAB07AOYAKAPK0AViBVhdAaxABPTUagBKVwG4gA

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo but seems your expected Object doesn't seem to match it's type definition: `a: 10` doesn't match `myType[a] as string`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that useState has an initial value, in this case it's an empty object `{}`. I would assume you are logging the values before they are set.

```
const Component = () => {
  const [allArrays, setAllArrays] = useState<AllArraysObject>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const sampleObject = { "1": [ { a: 10, b: "Hello" }, { a: 11, b: "Hi" } ] }
    setAllArrays(sampleObject);
  }, [])

  console.log(Object.keys(allArrays))
  // This be Array(0) on mount until setAllArrays is set
  // when useEffect issues a side-effect

  // so make a guard if object is empty
  if (Object.keys(allArrays).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object) {
    // null else set to anything you desire
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>{/* use allArrays */}</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I will try this and report back

Comment: Thanks, your solution seems to work fine! All that I in fact had to do was `useEffect(() => { setAllArrays({}); }, [])` Can you please elaborate on why I need to set up a useEffect?

Comment: Okay, so I realize that I do not even need to `setAllArrays({})` only inside useEffect. If I simply set my state to `{}` before setting a value into it, my function works. This is very unexpected.